# Elasticsearch: How to sort a result of a Query String query?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch to search Japanese documents, and combining multiple fields (Morphological analysis + N-Gram) for querying.

The query below:

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "bool":{  
      "must":{  
        "query_string":{  
          "query":"QUERY_KEYWORD",
          "fields":[  
            "title",
            "description",
            "content",
            "content.ngram^3"
          ]
        }
      },
      "should":[  
        [  
          {  
            "range":{  
              "created":{  
                "boost":"5",
                "gte":"now-1M"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
  "sort":{
      "view_count": {"order": "desc"}
  }
}
```

returns **every document in the index** sorted by `view_count` (ignoring the score from `query_string`), which is isn't what I want.

Multilevel Sorting doesn't work good either:

```
"sort": [
        { "view_count":   { "order": "desc" }},
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}
]
```

returns the same as the query above, and

```
"sort": [
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }},
        { "view_count":   { "order": "desc" }}
]
```

dosen't sort anything at all (I suspect `view_count` is only working as a tie-braker for `_score`).

The question is: How can I get documents matching `QUERY_KEYWORD` sorted by `view_count`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A sort overrules sorting by score. In your case I think you have to have a look at the function score query. Specifically the Field value factor.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor

With this, the amount of views influences the score based on the number of views.

Comment: Thanks. Is my understanding that Function Score Queries works against another query? I've realized that the `query_string` query itself returns every single document in the index, so it might be impossible to get a nice sort result.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean, if you provide no query argument to a query_string query it equals the match_all query. But if you are actually looking for a word, the query_string query will not return all documents.